# How to insert form into node/add page

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I am currently developing a module with a custom content type. In the node/add for this content type, I need to be insert a form that can retrieves data from an API, that will later be displayed on the page.

What is the best way to insert that form into the node/add page?

Should I use a hook_form_alter? Or should I make a custom field? This portion of the form will most likely involve AJAX, so I don't know if that will change anything.

Let me know if I need to clarify anything, and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Whether you create a custom field then modify it later, or create it completely in code, you need to use hook_form_alter in your custom module and add/edit your field that way and add the ajax call inside this function.

If you create a custom field in config, then there's now a config dependency you will need to somehow move from your dev environment to production (either thru [Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) or [Configuration](https://www.drupal.org/project/configuration) modules). On the other hand, if you add all through your custom module you won't need to worry about config changes, so IMO that is a better way.